# Using Sphinx with a distutils-built C extension

Tags: python, distutils, python-sphinx

I have written a Python module including a submodule written in C: the module itself is called `foo` and the C part is `foo._bar`. The structure looks like:

```
src/ 
  foo/__init__.py   <- contains the public stuff 
  foo/_bar/bar.c    <- the C extension
doc/                <- Sphinx configuration
  conf.py
  ...
```

`foo/__init__.py` imports `_bar` to augment it, and the useful stuff is exposed in the `foo` module. This works fine when it's built, but obviously won't work in uncompiled form, since `_bar` doesn't exist until it's built.

I'd like to use Sphinx to document the project, and use the [autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) extension on the `foo` module. This means I need to build the project before I can build the documentation.

Since I build with distutils, the built module ends up in some variably named dir `build/lib.linux-ARCH-PYVERSION` — which means I can't just hard-code the directory into a Sphinx' `conf.py`.

So how do I configure my distutils `setup.py` script to run the Sphinx builder over the built module?

For completeness, here's the call to `setup` (the 'fake' things are custom builders that subclass `build` and `build_ext`):

```
setup(cmdclass = {
        'fake': fake,
        'build_ext_fake' : build_ext_fake
      },
      package_dir = {'': 'src'},
      packages = ['foo'],
      name = 'foo',
      version = '0.1',
      description = desc,
      ext_modules = [module_real])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since distutils has a way of figuring out the variable build path, why not just use it?

```
import distutils.command.build
from distutils.dist import Distribution

b = distutils.command.build.build(Distribution())
b.initialize_options()
b.finalize_options()

print b.build_temp

# If you're building a library, you might need:
print b.build_lib

# Other values of interest are:
b.build_purelib
b.build_platlib
b.build_scripts
b.build_base
```

Even thought the distutils docs are sparse, [here you'll find one-liners](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.command.build) about what kinds of build are there.

Comment: That's a pretty good approach — I could put that right in `conf.py` (I think). I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: Aha... I needed to use `build_lib`, not `build_temp`, and mess around with my cross compilation, but it seems to be working (and on the extension part too, as an added bonus!)

Comment: Cool, if you want I can add more detail (or add an answer with your exact steps so others can benefit).

Comment: My use case (for building) is pretty bizarre: 32-bit only static lib, cross compiled from amd64... hence the `fake` entry, to make it a little easier to do all of this. I doubt those extra details will be helpful to anyone but me :)

Answer (score 2):

There are simpler ways to get the build dir name:

```
>>> from distutils.util import get_platform
>>> get_platform()
'linux-x86_64'
```

I’ll let you finish the string concatenation :)

Another way to solve your problem is to create a setup.cfg file alongside your setup.py with this content:

```
[build_ext]
inplace = 1
```

This will build your extension modules in its parent package directory.  Sphinx should see it.